# anchor tag dash on hover

Tags: css, anchor

I've been seeing a funny dash on anchor hovers.  I think it's mostly when there is an image in it.  It's not the standard underline which I can fix with text-decoration:none;

I've been fixing it with rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) but I wonder if there is a better way so I do it once to an entire site (because I obviously don't want text anchors to have to color)

here is my example, although it's not limited to this site
http://weinberg-michael.sesamehub.com/kenosha-office-tour

the social icons have this problem

Comment: The 'dash' on the social icons in the linked example is `text-decoration:underline` on `:hover`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `font-size: 0;` to solve this.  The problem is the white space when nesting tags in `inline` elements.  You're seeing the space between the close of the opening `<a>` and the beginning of the `<img>` tag.

Here's an alternate solution, as well:

```
<a href="#"><!--
  --><img src="myImg.jpg" /><!--
--></a>
```

Also, your hover rule for `a` elements has a `text-decoration` underline as well.  Removing that will preserve the `white-space` stuff, but not display the underline.

Comment: this isn't going to work.  I can't just say font-size:0 across the site.   and it's not an underline problem, I've tried that before.

Interesting idea about the white space although, I'm not really sure that is the problem

Comment: Don't use it across the site, just use it on your `<a>` tags that have an image.

Comment: I can also guarantee you that it is a problem.  Also, you've got `text-decoration:underline` on your `:hover` rule.